# MySQL - Settings and results inconsistent with research (wrong default storage engine, foreign keys referencing renamed tables)

Tags: mysql

I'm in the process of learning MySQL, but have noticed that the results I am getting are occasionally inconsistent with what is described in tutorials and other reference material.

First, I am using a version of MySQL greater than 5.7 (specifically, 5.7.14), and have read that the default table type/storage engine should be InnoDB. However, unless specified otherwise, the tables I create are MyISAM.

Second, the material I have read indicate "If a table is renamed, foreign keys pointing to the table are not automatically updated, and must be dropped and recreated manually". However, I have tested this repeatedly and am finding that my foreign keys ARE, in fact, automatically updated. I am not complaining (it seems to me that in most cases this behavior would be preferable), but I am a bit perplexed.

Have I read incorrect material (or read the material incorrectly)? Do I have some nonstandard version of MySQL installed? If not, what are some possible explanations for these discrepancies?

Comment: Which tutorial you are following?

Comment: I'm following several tutorials, but the one that made me first notice the differences was http://www.mysqltutorial.org

Comment: You should check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ And if you're really curious, replace '5.7' in the url with the version the tutorials are using. You'll spot the differences

Comment: First, i have tried with MySql, 5.7.12 and default engine type is InnoDB, not sure why you are getting default engine type as MyISAM. Can you check the mysql --version just to make sure you are using the right version.  
Second, If you rename the table, references get updated itself.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.7.14 (as stated above). Also, I'm confused by these two statements which seem to contradict one another:

Comment: RENAME TABLE changes internally generated foreign key constraint names and user-defined foreign key constraint names that contain the string “tbl_name_ibfk_” to reflect the new table name. InnoDB interprets foreign key constraint names that contain the string “tbl_name_ibfk_” as internally generated names.

Comment: Foreign keys that point to the renamed table are not automatically updated. In such cases, you must drop and re-create the foreign keys in order for them to function properly.